# How come va_arg returns the address 0, then 1 then 2?

Tags: objective-c, ios, variadic-functions

I'm retrieving va_args but I'm not sure why it sometimes return 0, 1, 2 and so on.  It crashes my program when I try to access it, and I have no way of asserting what it returns.

Any ideas?

Background: I'm programming in iOS.

```
void strngCls::Form(*wchar_t wCh, va_list argList)
{

    va_list argListTest = argList;
    const wchar_t *ws1 = va_arg(argListTest, const wchar_t *);
    const wchar_t *ws2 = va_arg(argListTest, const wchar_t *);

    if(ws1!=NULL && ws1!=(const wchar_t *)1 && ws2!=NULL)
    {
        int asd=wcslen(ws1);

        int asd2=wcslen(ws2);
        NSLog(@"ws1 = %d, ws2 = %d",asd,asd2);

        NSString *s1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:ws1 length:sizeof(wchar_t) *   wcslen(ws1) encoding: NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"s1 %@",s1);
        NSString *s2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:ws2 length:sizeof(wchar_t) * wcslen(ws2) encoding: NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"s2 %@",s2);


        NSString *iosString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ = %@", s1, s2];
        const char *ws3 = [iosString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
        [s1 release];
        [s2 release];

        x = vswprintf(m_pchData, GetAllocLength(), (LPCTSTR)ws3, argListTest);

    }
    else if(ws1!=NULL && ws1!=(const wchar_t *)1)
    {
        int asd=wcslen(ws1);

        NSLog(@"ws1 = %d",asd);

        NSString *s1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:ws1 length:sizeof(wchar_t) * wcslen(ws1) encoding: NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"s1 %@",s1);
        NSString *iosString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", s1];
        const char *ws3 = [iosString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
        [s1 release];
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post your code here?  Without anything to look at, it's almost impossible for us to help.

Comment: Are you sure you're using it right? There's tons on how to use it. The code would answer this question.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I don't see how we could help.

Comment: updated with code! The paste didn't format properly, please see just above the block of code for more code.  Thanks.

Comment: As it is, we have no idea if you set it up correctly to use.

Comment: I suspect you may be calling `va_start` or `va_arg` incorrectly, or not calling `va_start` at all!  Like most others here, I also vote for you editing your question to include the code.

Comment: Can you narrow it down to a small complete program that exhibits the problem? It would be helpful to see (a trimmed version of) the entire function definition and the call to it. And the code looks like Objective-C, which is neither C nor C++.

Comment: Where is `argListTest` defined and initialised?  Where is the function header?

Comment: I will post those! Right now I just stepped out.  Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Hey guys, I just added extra code on the top. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a call to `va_start`:

```
void strngCls::Form(*wchar_t wCh, va_list argList)
{
    va_list argListTest = argList;
    va_start(argListTest, wCh);
    const wchar_t *ws1 = va_arg(argListTest, const wchar_t *);
    const wchar_t *ws2 = va_arg(argListTest, const wchar_t *);
```

Also, call `va_end` when you're done:

```
    va_end(argListTest);
}
```